# Arduino IDE: Board nodemcuv2 (platform esp8266, package esp8266) is unknown

Tags: arduino-ide, library, nodemcu

I am receiving this error after reinstalling Arduino IDE (everything was working fine [same components, same code]):

> Board nodemcuv2 (platform esp8266, package esp8266) is unknown

I have recently reinstalled ESP8266 libraries. Could that have caused this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did some digging and found a solution that worked for me:

Uninstall (by logically deleting folders) and reinstall ESP Libraries.

Open Arduino IDE
Go to FILE -> PREFERENCES

[image]

Open the preferences folder (this works in Linux, Mac and Windows) 
Go to PACKAGES > ESP8266 > HARDWARE > ESP8266

[image]

Delete all libraries (if your issue is similar to mine and to others', you should have 2 or more folders, with different versions).

Restart Arduino IDE.
Go to SKETCH > INCLUDE LIBRARY > MANAGE LIBRARIES
Install ESP8266 Community 
Go to TOOLS > BOARD and scroll down to your model of NODEMCU

Run compile and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: Good work finding a solution and answering your question! I feel like this wording: *"Delete all libraries"* could be confusing. I'm not sure if maybe it's common to call folders "libraries" but in the context of Arduino, where the term has a specific meaning which is not applicable here, I think it would be better to instead say "Delete all folders".

Comment: FYI,  it should not be necessary to delete both version folders. The problem is caused by the Arduino IDE not completely removing the previous version when you update to a different one so you could just delete the previous version's folder only, which saves you from having to do the reinstall step. However, your instructions work fine to solve the problem.

Comment: i tried deleting just the oldest, but it did not work.  You are correct: delete all libraries in the ESP8266 folder.

Comment: Many thanks! In fact, my another computer and Mac does not show this and my working PC seems before was installed something causes this error. even though I un-install the arduino the problem still there. without your sharing I cannot fix it. thanks again!